# Converting string "decimal" to DecimalType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Due to an over-complicated process, I need to convert strings representing a data type to an actual `org.apache.spark.sql.types` data type.  I've got a simple function almost working.

```
def getType (s: String): DataType = {
  s match {
    case "string" => StringType
    ...
    case "decimal" => DecimalType
    //case "decimal" => org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType

  }
}
```

Both versions of the decimal line cause it to fail:

```
found  : org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.type
required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
```

How do I handle this?

Comment: Is `DecimalType` a companion object or an instance of a class inheriting from `DataType`? If you want an actual `DecimalType` instance, I think you will have to use `DataTypes.createDecimalType()`. Or if you want the companions, you can just return an `Any`, I guess

Comment: DecimalType is a normal class, so you need to instantiate it - whereas the StringType and DataType are abstract classes. I think if you provide it like this  `case "decimal" => DecimalType()`, it may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to create a DecimalType.

You could use `new`(Java version) to create a DecimalType.

The default precision and scale is (10, 0) `new DecimalType()`, but you can provide `precision` and `scale`. The `precision` can be up to 38, `scale` can also be up to 38 (less or equal to `precision`).

For example

```scala
    def getType (s: String): DataType = {
      s match {
        case "string" => StringType
        case "decimal" => new DecimalType(precision = 18, scale = 12)
        case "decimalV2" =>  DataTypes.createDecimalType() // This works too, default precision and scale
        case "decimalV3" => DataTypes.createDecimalType(precision = 12, scale = 8) // if you want to provide precision and scale
        //case "decimal" => org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
      }
    }
```